# How can I upload images to another host domain with php?

Tags: php, image, upload

My admin panel is on `test.com` and I have functionality in my admin panel that allows the uploading of images. But the images must be uploaded to `subdomain.test.com`.

My server is CentOS 7.2 minimal and I installed DirectAdmin on server.

What is the best solution for this issue?

Comment: So, you are looking to upload to a subdomain? That's not necessarily a different host. How is the subdomain configured? Is it simply using a subdirectory of your web host? Before confusing the issue please explain what the file structure relationship is between the image upload destination and your upload script.

Comment: No,
/home/test/domains/test.com/public_html

/home/subtest/domains/sub.test.com/public_html

Comment: improved grammar and syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding and experience it is not possible to direct upload, but following are some way to achieve this.

1. In your case, as you are looking to upload/save the images to sub domain created under that domain as mentioned by you. **You can upload the file to your main domain and then move the images to your sub domain file using server root paths.** It is easy to implement as you just want to save image on your **subdomain**.
2. Define some web service application on your subdomain which will read the images through bystream passed from main domain. i.e your main domain will call web services of subdomain to save the images. (It will require extra efforts)

Comment: for sync this folders how i can do? Best solution

Comment: When the new image is uploaded, the approach that you will use will copy/move the images to subdomain each time. If you are just copying then it will create mirror copy. So i don't think there will any issues occurs.